# Disable block from editor based on post type

Tags: hooks, block-editor, hierarchical, post-type, get-post

I've made a Gutenberg block which is only appropriate to show on hierarchical post types, so I want to disable it from the block inserter for non-hierarchical post types.

I thought about how to achieve this in PHP, but the [WordPress documentation on registering blocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/writing-your-first-block-type/#enqueuing-block-scripts) seems to suggest that blocks should be registered in PHP on the `init` hook and not a later hook where you could check if the post being edited is hierarchical. At the time the `init` hook fires, the currently viewed post is not yet available via e.g. `get_post()`, so I can't check its `post_type`.

I also thought about how to achieve this in the (JavaScript) script that I register with the `editor_script` property passed to `register_block_type`, but I don't know how to check the post type being edited to make it possible to halt the block registration in the case of non-hierarchical post types. It also seems a bit silly to enqueue and run the block script only for the script to decide that it shouldn't do anything, so ideally I would like to implement this checking in PHP.

Is there some standard way to make a block available only for specific post types, ideally in PHP?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `allowed_block_types` hook:

```
<?php
function wpse_allowed_block_types($allowed_block_types, $post) {
    // Limit blocks in 'post' post type
    if($post->post_type == 'post') {
        // Return an array containing the allowed block types
        return array(
            'core/paragraph',
            'core/heading'
        );
    }
    // Limit blocks in 'page' post type
    elseif($post->post_type == 'page') {
        return array(
            'core/list'
        );
    }
    // Allow defaults in all other post types
    else {
        return $allowed_block_types;
    }
}
add_filter('allowed_block_types', 'wpse_allowed_block_types', 10, 2);
?>
```

Tweak with as many or as few conditions as you need. You can also enable non-Core blocks by identifying their namespace and name and putting those in the array.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way though to explicitly disallow a block, instead of having to provide a whitelist? As far as I understand this filter provides `true` by default, i.e. all blocks, instead of an actual list of block names which I could remove mine from. I'd rather not have to update my plugin every time a new core block is added, or remove other plugins' blocks by not adding them to my whitelist this sort of function.

Comment: As of January there was not yet a way to blacklist. See related https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/326959/gutenberg-disallow-certain-custom-blocks-but-keep-all-core-blocks

Comment: Thanks. That's unfortunate. I hope the developers add some whitelist mechanism in the future.

Comment: Thank you for this. EXACTLY what I was looking for & totally nailed my use-case.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but I was trying to do something similar. I have created a post type, and rather than use custom meta boxes to add/save post meta, I'm using blocks. Given the purpose of such a block, it should really only show for the relevant post type.

I found the following works. You can use the unregisterBlockType() function to unregister your block for any post types that are not your own.

There are two steps.

1. Enqueue a JS file when not on your post type.

```
function my_function() {
    if ( get_post_type() != 'my-post-type' ) {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'my-script',
            'path/to/js/my-script.js',
            array( 'original-block-js' ),
            '1.0.0',
            true
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_function' );
```

Note 'original-block-js' as a dependency. This refers to the JS file that's registering your block in the first place. We are ensuring the code to unregister the block is loaded *after* the code that registers it.

2. Add the following to your JS file.

```
const { unregisterBlockType } = wp.blocks;

wp.domReady( function() {
    unregisterBlockType( 'my-name-space/block-name' );
} );
```

Replace my-name-space/block-name with your block name.

**UPDATE**

The original poster wanted to hide the block on any non-hierarchical post types. That's a slightly different use case. But you can get there by just adjusting the conditional with is_post_type_hierarchical().

Answer (score 1):

To disable specific blocks, you can use the allowed_block_types_all hooks. Follow the approach below and make sure to replace the post type name for your needs.

```
<?php
function disable_specific_blocks( $allowed_block_types, $post ) {
    // An array of block names to disable
    $disabled_blocks = array(
        'core/table',
        'core/image',
        'core/gallery',
    );
  
    // Use this condition to disable blocks on certain post types, otherwise you can remove this IF condition
    if ( $post->post_type === 'post' ) {
        $allowed_block_types = array_diff( $allowed_block_types, $disabled_blocks );
    }

    return $allowed_block_types;
}
add_filter( 'allowed_block_types_all', 'disable_specific_blocks', 10, 2 );
?>
```

For complete guide, you can follow this tutorial on [how to disable specific blocks on the WordPress block editor](https://jeffreycarandang.com/how-to-disable-specific-blocks-in-the-wordpress-gutenberg-block-editor/).

Comment: I was just looking for something like this, unfortunately the array_diff fails with the first arg, as $allowed_block_types defaults to true. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/allowed_block_types_all/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to whitelist the blocks that you want to use on your post you can use this method from the WordPress handbook https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#using-a-whitelist

```
// my-plugin.js
var allowedBlocks = [
    'core/paragraph',
    'core/image',
    'core/html',
    'core/freeform'
];

wp.blocks.getBlockTypes().forEach( function( blockType ) {
    if ( allowedBlocks.indexOf( blockType.name ) === -1 ) {
        wp.blocks.unregisterBlockType( blockType.name );
    }
} );
```