# How to remove the core embed blocks in WordPress 5.6?

Tags: wp-admin, block-editor

Following up on [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/326959/32946), I want to remove some of the default (core) embed blocks in the WordPress block editor. As of WordPress 5.6, the blocks are no longer available under the `core-embed/*` namespace.

How can I unregister individual core embed blocks?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With WordPress 5.6 ([Gutenberg v8.8.0](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/releases/tag/v8.8.0)), the implementation of the `core-embed/*` blocks changed (see pull request [#24090](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/24090): Refactor embed block to single block with block variations). There are now 43 blocks with block variations of the `core/embed` block.

Available core blocks are:

```html
core/paragraph
core/image
core/heading
core/gallery
core/list
core/quote
core/shortcode
core/archives
core/audio
core/button
core/buttons
core/calendar
core/categories
core/code
core/columns
core/column
core/cover
core/embed
core/file
core/group
core/freeform
core/html
core/media-text
core/latest-comments
core/latest-posts
core/missing
core/more
core/nextpage
core/preformatted
core/pullquote
core/rss
core/search
core/separator
core/block
core/social-links
core/social-link
core/spacer
core/subhead
core/table
core/tag-cloud
core/text-columns
core/verse
core/video
```

Unregister embeds altogether (including variations):

```js
wp.domReady(function () {
  wp.blocks.unregisterBlockType('core/embed');
});
```

The blocks previously listed as `core-embed/*` are now available as a variation of `core/embed`:

```js
console.table(wp.blocks.getBlockVariations('core/embed'));
```

Available block variations of `core/embed` are:

```html
amazon-kindle
animoto
cloudup
collegehumor
crowdsignal
dailymotion
facebook
flickr
imgur
instagram
issuu
kickstarter
meetup-com
mixcloud
pinterest
pocketcasts
reddit
reverbnation
screencast
scribd
slideshare
smugmug
soundcloud
speaker-deck
spotify
ted
tiktok
tumblr
twitter
videopress
vimeo
wolfram-cloud
wordpress
wordpress-tv
youtube
```

You can unregister a single variation like this:

```js
wp.domReady(function () {
  wp.blocks.unregisterBlockVariation('core/embed', 'twitter');
});
```

Or unregister all variations and only allow individual variations:

```
wp.domReady(function () {
  const allowedEmbedBlocks = [
    'vimeo',
    'youtube',
  ];
  wp.blocks.getBlockVariations('core/embed').forEach(function (blockVariation) {
    if (-1 === allowedEmbedBlocks.indexOf(blockVariation.name)) {
      wp.blocks.unregisterBlockVariation('core/embed', blockVariation.name);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you have to unregister each variation individually or can you just unregister the block itself? And instead of hardcoding, why not use the result from `wp.blocks.getBlockVariations('core/embed')`?

Comment: @kero Removing the embed block also removes all the variations (see updated answer above). It might be useful to keep the embed block and just remove individual variations. Maybe I want to embed videos (from YouTube and Vimeo) but get rid of all the other embeds.

Comment: So there is no longer any way to remove a particular embed block using PHP only the whole set?

Answer (score 10):

As a theme developer I often want the embed blocks restricted to youtube and vimeo, just as Sven. So, following Sven's answer:
In my php code:

```
function my_theme_deny_list_blocks() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'deny-list-blocks',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/deny-list-blocks.js',
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-dom-ready', 'wp-edit-post' )
    );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'my_theme_deny_list_blocks' );
```

In my new javascript file deny-list-blocks.js:

```
wp.domReady( function() {

    var embed_variations = [
                            'amazon-kindle',
                            'animoto',
                            'cloudup',
                            'collegehumor',
                            'crowdsignal',
                            'dailymotion',
                            'facebook',
                            'flickr',
                            'imgur',
                            'instagram',
                            'issuu',
                            'kickstarter',
                            'meetup-com',
                            'mixcloud',
                            'reddit',
                            'reverbnation',
                            'screencast',
                            'scribd',
                            'slideshare',
                            'smugmug',
                            'soundcloud',
                            'speaker-deck',
                            'spotify',
                            'ted',
                            'tiktok',
                            'tumblr',
                            'twitter',
                            'videopress',
                            //'vimeo'
                            'wordpress',
                            'wordpress-tv',
                            //'youtube'
                ];

    for (var i = embed_variations.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        wp.blocks.unregisterBlockVariation('core/embed', embed_variations[i]);
    }
} );
```

Notice that **vimeo** and **youtube** are commented. Nevertheless, it should be a better way to do this, for instance disabling all variations in one line, then enabling only the desired ones.

Also worth noticing that all themes using the **allowed_block_types** filter to disable embeds will have to be modified when updating wordpress to 5.6.

Comment: Thank you! For me, the working solution was a combination of your answer and @Sven's answer: I took the PHP part from your answer (in functions.php) and used the very last JS code block from Sven's answer as the separate `deny-list-blocks.js` file which your PHP function links to.

Comment: @Marc what would it be a suitable alternative to allowed_block_types filter?

Comment: @Johannes is there a link to your solution?

Comment: @Giorgio25b  Well, there are two public websites where I applied that solution, but as long as you don't have  a user account for these (which won't be possible), you wouldn't be able to check any of that code or see which blocks are available for users.

Comment: @Johannes no, I meant is there a shared snippet, a gist, a POW, something to see your implemented code without having to share details of any of your production projects ;-)

Comment: is there a PHP equivalent to this?

Comment: I've updated it based on latest block names:

https://gist.github.com/csaborio001/03e4a4c024055dccb381853eda02119c

I can't get rid of:

* theme\categories
* theme\tags
* theme\next-post
* theme\previous-post