# getBlockVariations(…) is undefined in Widget and Template Part editors but not Post Editor

Tags: widgets, block-editor

I'm using [this technique](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/379612/how-to-remove-the-core-embed-blocks-in-wordpress-5-6) to hide various embed blocks:

```
wp.domReady( function() {

    /*
     * Hide Embed Variations
     */
    wp.blocks.getBlockVariations('core/embed').forEach(function (embed) {

        // loop through a bunch of embeds

    });

});
```

The file with that script is registered and enqueued like this:

```
<?php
wp_register_script(
    'block-editor-js',
    plugins_url( 'js/block-editor.js', dirname(__FILE__) ),
    array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-dom-ready', 'wp-edit-post' )
);

wp_localize_script(
    'block-editor-js',
    'editorOptions',
    [ /* some values */ ]
);

wp_enqueue_script( 'block-editor-js' );
```

**This works as expected in the block editor!**

It does not work in the block-based widget editor or the template part editor. In Firefox in both cases, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: wp.blocks.getBlockVariations(...) is undefined

I am totally flummoxed as to what the issue is. My two guesses are that I need some additional dependencies on the pages that break or that `domReady` is too early and I need to hook onto somewhere later.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Here's why did you get an `undefined`

The function itself was defined, but the function call (`wp.blocks.getBlockVariations( 'core/embed' )`) returned an `undefined` because by the time that you called the function, the block/Gutenberg editor had not yet been ***initialized***.

Hence, `undefined` was returned instead of an array of block variations, because core block types like Embed had not yet been registered — and if you had called `wp.blocks.getBlockTypes()`, you'd see that `core/embed` is not in the list.

#### How to ensure your code runs properly

WordPress uses [`wp_add_inline_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) to add an inline script which calls the function that initializes the editor, so you need to add the same dependency passed to `wp_add_inline_script()`, which is the 1st parameter, to your script's dependencies ( the 3rd parameter for `wp_register_script()` ):

- For the block-based *post* editor, the dependency is `wp-edit-post` which will load `wp-includes/js/dist/edit-post.js` that defines `wp.editPost.initializeEditor()` and is used to initialize the block-based post editor.

  See source on GitHub: [`wp-admin/edit-form-blocks.php`, line 303](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.1/src/wp-admin/edit-form-blocks.php#L303) and [line 290](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.1/src/wp-admin/edit-form-blocks.php#L290)
- For the block-based *widgets* editor, the dependency is `wp-edit-widgets` which will load `wp-includes/js/dist/edit-widgets.js` that defines `wp.editWidgets.initialize()` and is used to initialize the block-based widgets editor.

  See source on GitHub: [`wp-admin/widgets-form-blocks.php`, lines 38-46](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.1/src/wp-admin/widgets-form-blocks.php#L38-L46)
- For the Site Editor, the dependency is `wp-edit-site` which will load `wp-includes/js/dist/edit-site.js` that defines `wp.editSite.initializeEditor()` and is used to initialize the Site Editor.

  See source on GitHub: [`wp-admin/site-editor.php`, lines 120-128](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.1/src/wp-admin/site-editor.php#L120-L128)

So, just add either `wp-edit-post`, `wp-edit-widgets` or `wp-edit-site` to your script's dependencies, depending on the current admin page, or the editor type (post/widgets/site).

That way, the editor initialization function would already be *defined *and* called* when you call `wp.blocks.getBlockVariations()` and thus, you'd get the proper result.

**Working Example**

```php
$deps = array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-dom-ready' );

global $pagenow;
// If we're on the Widgets admin page, add wp-edit-widgets to the dependencies.
if ( 'widgets.php' === $pagenow ) {
    $deps[] = 'wp-edit-widgets';
// If we're on the Site Editor admin page, add wp-edit-site to the dependencies.
} elseif ( 'site-editor.php' === $pagenow ) {
    $deps[] = 'wp-edit-site';
// If we're on the post/Page/CPT editing screen (e.g. at wp-admin/post.php), add
// wp-edit-post to the dependencies.
} else {
    $deps[] = 'wp-edit-post';
}

wp_register_script(
    'block-editor-js',
    plugins_url( 'js/block-editor.js', dirname(__FILE__) ),
    $deps
);
```

**Notes**

- I used the [`enqueue_block_editor_assets` action/hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enqueue_block_editor_assets/) to run the above code.
- The minified version of the JS files mentioned above, where the file name ends with `.min.js`, will be loaded instead when [script debugging](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#script_debug) is not enabled.