# Limit Gutenberg blocks available to users to choose from

Tags: posts, block-editor, blog

I am using the `allowed_block_types_all` filter to choose certain blocks the users can choose from. I have just added one here as an example. This works fine but my issue comes in when trying to choose embeds.

```
add_filter( 'allowed_block_types_all', 'usr_allowed_block_types' );
function usr_allowed_block_types( $allowed_blocks ) {
  return array(
    'core/paragraph',
    'core-embed/twitter'
  );
}
```

I see the paragraph but not twitter. If I add `core/embed` then I get ALL embeds which I really don't want.

Comment: What if you tried `return array('core/paragraph', 'core/embed', 'core-embed/twitter');`, maybe that will open the option for embed and because you used the twitter, lock it only for twitter

Comment: @Buttered_Toast, forgot to mention I already tried that. It doesn't show any embeds if I do that.

Comment: Fart, ok, I found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/326959/gutenberg-disallow-certain-custom-blocks-but-keep-all-core-blocks) maybe that could help, it has a JS option you could try. I never used gutenberg but this post seem like a good solution

Comment: @Buttered_Toast the JS option seems to be working, thanks! LOL @ 'Fart' by the way :)

Comment: twitter blocks are actually embed blocks, its just a block variant, there is no separate block name for it, what you want is not how to disable a block, but how to disable a block variant

Comment: @Buttered_Toast can you post that as the answer below? or is this a duplicate question?

Comment: @TomJNowell I think it would be better if OP added his solution as the answer, plus the post I pointed to in the comments goes it great detail about how to achieve this

Comment: @user8463989 can you post what you did as the solution so other people with this problem can use it?

Comment: @TomJNowell Apologies for delay, posted the answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the functions.php file I added

```
add_filter( 'allowed_block_types_all', 'func_allowed_block_types' );
function func_allowed_block_types( $allowed_blocks ) {
 
    return array(
        'core/embed'
    );
}
```

Then in my plugin I added this JS to the javascript file to enable only the embed blocks I wanted (Twitter, youTube and Vimeo)

```
wp.domReady( function() {
    const allowedEmbedBlocks = [
        'twitter','youtube', 'vimeo'
    ];

    wp.blocks.getBlockType( 'core/embed' ).variations.forEach( function( blockVariation ) {
        if (
            allowedEmbedBlocks.indexOf( blockVariation.name ) === -1
        ) {
            wp.blocks.unregisterBlockVariation( 'core/embed', blockVariation.name );
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: I don't think the PHP filter is needed, it might even cause issues, the JS on the other hand looks good